# apt-get is trying to install when doing a remove --purge

Tags: apt, uninstall, ppa

I'm trying to remove a package using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ka-lite
```

but when I run that command, it tries to download and install another package instead of removing the one I'm asking for.
Any idea why that happens or how to remove only the package?

This is the output (in spanish)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ka-lite-bundle ka-lite-gtk
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ka-lite-bundle
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ka-lite*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ka-lite-bundle
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 375 MB of archives.
After this operation, 485 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Outout from apt-cache rdepends:

```
ka-lite
Reverse Depends:
 |ka-lite-gtk
  ka-lite-bundle
  ka-lite-raspberry-pi
```

Comment: Which packages?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact output of the command? It would help a lot with answering your question if we know what exactly is going on :) It may be that because you are removing a certain package it is installing a replacement because that package is required by some other package.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I added the info

Comment: Please restart the command after you have started `LANG=C`

Comment: @A.B. ok, I edited with the English output

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache rdepends ka-lite`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple, also without knowing which package you mean.

You're trying to remove a package that is required by another package. Since there is an alternative for the package to be removed, this alternative is installed.

---

You have the following alternative.

- Do not remove the package
- Accept the alternative
- Find and remove the package that needs the to be removed package or the alternative via

  ```
  apt-cache rdepends ka-lite
  ```

---

After some googling, you have used a PPA for the installation. Therefore use the command below

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:learningequality/ka-lite
```

Comment: That means that I have to download and install the other package and then remove that package?

Comment: No. You have to remove the "parent" package. But that could be a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, the output was like:
```ka-lite
Reverse Depends:
 |ka-lite-gtk
  ka-lite-bundle
  ka-lite-raspberry-pi```

Comment: Purge the PPA as described in my answer.

Comment: It worked! So it removed the PPA first, and then I was able to remove the package and its dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: `also without knowing which package you mean` - but i remove php-8.1-cli, already have 8.2, don't want to install 8.3, but it will

Comment: "You're trying to remove a package that is required by another package." Isn't `apt` the one saying that `ka-lite-bundle` can be removed? Then why does it ask me to install it again? Is it because `ka-lite-bundle` is also a dependency of another package? If so, then why can't `apt` detect such case instead of asking me to remove and install it again?